# extjs form markInvalid

Tags: extjs

i want to use this.form.markInvalid directly from the form.

i have 2 items in my form:

code:

```
  items: [
            { 
            fieldLabel: 'Name',
            name: 'name'
            }
            ,{
            id: 'e' ,
            fieldLabel: 'Email',
            name: 'email'
        }]
```

when the user click on a button i am calling `this.form.markInvalid({'e':'email is invalid'});`

i want to mark email item as invalid with the error message: "email is invalid".

But i  get an error message when i press the button:

```
this.form is undefined
 this.form.markInvalid({'e':'email is invalid'});
```

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the button handler/listener did you define the correct scope?

The function that is registered to the click event should have access to the `this.form` property. `this` in your case probably points to the button itself instead of the the formPanel.

You can easily change the scope of the listener by using createDelegate() or adding an extra argument when registering your listener like this:

```
myButton.on('click', function(){
    console.log(this, this.id);
}, this); // <= notice the "this" argument here!
```

BUT!
Why are you validating your email like this? You could as easily add a vtype to your field config and let ExtJS do it all for you.

```
items: [{ 
    fieldLabel: 'Name',
    name: 'name'
},{
    id: 'e' ,
    fieldLabel: 'Email',
    name: 'email',
    vtype: 'email'
}]
```

Comment: thx ChrisR, my scope was wrong, i fixed if by using  appWiki.main_panel.getForm().markInvalid({'e':'error'});

Comment: also, you are right about the second method for validation. but i didn't use it beacuse 'email' field is just an example for future capabilites. anyway -> THX !